# How to wait for the GUI finishing its update - Swing

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

```
JPanel[] panels = new JPanel[5]; // lets just say its still filled and does not just contain null to keep it short
while(true){
  for(JPanel panel : panels){
    // set the color of the panel to different colors
  }
}
```

Im coloring a few panels in a permannent cyclus. Now my problem is, that the update of the gui has a delay because of the thread which is updating it. Now i am looking for a way to join this thread and wait exactly until it´s done before starting the next cyclus

```
JPanel[] panels = new JPanel[5];// lets just say its still filled and does not just contain null to keep it short
while(true){
  for(JPanel panel : panels){
    // set the color of the panel to different colors
  }
  // wait until the gui-update is over
}
```

Hope somebody can hlep me :)
Thanks!

Comment: SwingWorker http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html and http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/

Comment: Or [*How to Use Swing Timers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: If you want to burn the CPU: [`JComponent.paintImmediately(…)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintImmediately(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))